# How to make Hazelcast MapStore delete entry in persistence layer on entry eviction event

Tags: hazelcast

I want the entry in persistence layer (database) of a Hazelcast map to be deleted when that entry is evicted from the cache. But as I observed, the delete function of MapStore is only invoked whenever I directly remove the entry from the cache. Any solution to bind the MapStore.delete() with entryEvicted event?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this would be very dangerous behavior. Usually the in-memory map is that caching layer and not the 'system of record' when a backing store is used. You may find that all your records have been deleted from your database after the system has been idle for some time. If you're going to delete the records from the backing store on expiration, why have the backing store at all?

That being said, if you really want to do this, you should probably have a look at Entry Listeners. You can listen for Entry Evictions and then execute whatever logic you want, such as deleting the entry. Consider very carefully the performance impact of what you are doing though.

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#listening-for-map-events